# Change drupal module directory

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

```
Hello at the installation I want to change the modules directory on drupal 7 so i want to know if it possible or impossible.i want to change ../modules to ../mods/init and site/all/modules to ../mods/global
```

i tried changing the install.core.inc the line 
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/modules/
but i did get this message:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function field_attach_load() in F:\xamp\htdocs\cms\php\dp7_1\includes\entity.inc on line 354

Answer (score 2):

In Drupal 7, it considered best practice to keep modules in the sites/*/modules directory.

And it is considered very bad practice to edit any lines in Drupal core such as install.core.inc

See Drupal's "Never Hack Core" documentation https://www.drupal.org/best-practices/do-not-hack-core and their primary reasons:

> - You will make it complicated, difficult, or nearly impossible to
>     apply site updates such as Security and bug fixes.
> - You will make it difficult for those that come after to maintain the site.
> - You could possibly leave your site vulnerable to exploits.

It is not impossible, but it would be considered a very bad hack of core, create a lot of technical debt and overhead that would be experienced with every upgrade, and render other modules and functionality like drush useless without hacking them as well.